# Do people in USA have freedom in USA worship on Sunday?

Tags: worship, sunday

Yes or no

Sunday is not mark of the beast.

Comment: this might be more of a legal question. Can you clarify your question, how does mark of the beast tie into your question title?

Comment: This question would be better suited for [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour), though to get an answer it would need to be expanded to explain what the question actually means (since the obvious answer based on the number of people that will be attending religious services this weekend is a very definite "yes").